# Updating Database with JSON not executing update or delete

Tags: android, json

after the crashing problem been solved now the application is not executing the update or deleting 
when i update it crashes immediately but when i delete it shows me the toast and nothing happens then

this is the class

```
public class EditCard extends Activity {

    EditText txtName;
    EditText txtPosition;
    EditText txtCollege;
    EditText txtPhone;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;

    String cid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_card_details = "http://XXX";

    // url to update product
    private static final String url_update_card = "http://XXX";

    // url to delete product
    private static final String url_delete_card = "http://XXX";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_CARDS = "cards";
    private static final String TAG_CID = "cid";
    private static final String TAG_CNAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_POSITION = "position";
    private static final String TAG_COLLEGE = "college";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_card);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        // save button
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveCard);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DeleteCard);

        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        cid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_CID);

        // Getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetCardDetails().execute();

        // save button click event
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // starting background task to update product
                new SaveCardDetails().execute();
            }
        });

        // Delete button click event
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // deleting product in background thread
                new DeleteCard().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetCardDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditCard.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading card details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid", cid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_card_details, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray cardObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_CARDS); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject card = cardObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCard1);
                            txtPosition = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCard2);
                            txtCollege= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCard3);
                            txtPhone= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCard4);

                            // display product data in EditText
                            txtName.setText(card.getString(TAG_CNAME));
                            txtPosition.setText(card.getString(TAG_POSITION));
                            txtCollege.setText(card.getString(TAG_COLLEGE));
                            txtPhone.setText(card.getString(TAG_PHONE));

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
     * */
    class SaveCardDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditCard.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving Card ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Saving product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting updated data from EditTexts
            String name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String position = txtPosition.getText().toString();
            String college = txtCollege.getText().toString();
            String phone = txtPhone.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("position", position));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("college", college));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));

            // sending modified data through http request
            // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_card,
                    "POST", params);

            // check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The Student Card Updated sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /*****************************************************************
     * Background Async Task to Delete Product
     * */
    class DeleteCard extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditCard.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Card...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Deleting product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid", cid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_delete_card, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Delete Card", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // product successfully deleted
                    // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The Student Card deleted sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
}
```

and this is the LogCat when i update

```
07-18 01:15:53.053: W/dalvikvm(8740): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     at com.example.ahliaevents.EditCard$SaveCardDetails.doInBackground(EditCard.java:210)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     at com.example.ahliaevents.EditCard$SaveCardDetails.doInBackground(EditCard.java:1)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-18 01:15:53.383: E/AndroidRuntime(8740):     ... 4 more
```

and this is the LogCat when i delete

```
07-18 01:18:01.584: E/JSON Parser(8850): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Answer (score 0):

For your delete crash, you're not getting JSON back from the server, you're probably getting an error page.  The parser is expecting to see JSON and it sees what appears to be the beginning of an XML/XHTML document.

For your other crash, just look at your source at line 210.  You're getting a `NullPointerException`, which means that you expect something to be an object, but it's a null reference.

Most alarming is your use of `runOnUiThread()` within a `doInBackground()`  the whole point of doInBackground is to avoid the UI Thread.